# How to animate view controller cross dissolve while pushing via navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift

Current Codes :-

```
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcProfile")
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: What is the error? What do you wnat us to do? Please share the entire code!

Comment: Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this after push method :-

UIView.transition(with: self.navigationController!.view, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)